# Write into the internal flash memory using HAL_FLASH_Program STM32L0

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, hal

I'm trying to write some bytes of data at the specific region in the flash using HAL_FLASH_Program (uint32_t TypeProgram, uint32_t Address, uint32_t Data). But my current understanding of from HAL user manual at 19.2.7 [UM1749](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/41/78/8e/63/f9/32/44/12/DM00113898.pdf/files/DM00113898.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00113898.pdf) "Program word at a specified address" is unclear what does it mean? how can I write bytes e.g.: `char* demo="nucleo"` into memory.

```c
   char* demo="nucleo";
   int main(){
   .
   .
   ScratchWrite(FLASH_SCRATCH_START, demo);
   .
   .
   }

    uint32_t ScratchWrite(uint32_t destination, uint32_t *p_source)
   {
   
     HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
   
       /* Write the buffer to the memory */
      HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD,destination, p_source );
   
     HAL_FLASH_Lock();
   
     return status;
   }
```

Comment: that would be two words, 8 bytes so sure, do two writes.

Answer (score 4):

`HAL_FLASH_Program` allows you to write given number of bytes under specified address. First function argument `uint32_t TypeProgram` controls how large the chunk you want to write is. The possibilites are:

```
#define FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_BYTE        ((uint32_t)0x00U)  /*!< Program byte (8-bit) at a specified address           */
#define FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_HALFWORD    ((uint32_t)0x01U)  /*!< Program a half-word (16-bit) at a specified address   */
#define FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD        ((uint32_t)0x02U)  /*!< Program a word (32-bit) at a specified address        */
#define FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD  ((uint32_t)0x03U)  /*!< Program a double word (64-bit) at a specified address */
```

So in case of your question, FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD writes 32-bit (4 byte) value under specified address. For example:

```
HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, 0x8010000, *(uint32_t*)demo);
```

will write `"nucl"` under address `0x8010000`.

How large the chunks you want to program with `HAL_FLASH_Program` are is totally up to you and will affect performance if you choose small chunks (`FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_BYTE` for example) when programming large portion of flash.